# jquery отправка ajax только 1 заявки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть скрипт который отправляет данные через аякс. Но проблема что если нажать на кнопку 5 раз, то отправится 5 заявок. Как сделать чтобы только 1 отправлялась?

```
jQuery('#formsc').click('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = jQuery('#name').val();
  var phone = jQuery('#phone').val();

  if (phone != '') {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "send/send.php",
      data: jQuery('form#formsc').serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = "sucs.html";
        console.log('Ok, send!');
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log('Error. Not send.');
      }
    },);
  }
});
```

Comment: Нужно так чтоб из браузера отправил только 1 запрос?

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Можете добавить флаг на странице, и обновлять при отправке формы, а также проверять перед отправкой, но стоит обновить страницу, и можно будет ещё раз отправить.

**2**. Убирать данные из формы, тогда пользователю придётся каждый раз прописывать.

**3**. Но вообще я и то, и то ограничение я обойду, надо просто делать проверку на стороне сервера, js у клиента, доверять нельзя!

Comment: А как лучше сделать проверку на сервере?

Comment: @ЕвгенийСафронов как вариант - пишете в таблицу бд, например, время запроса и сессию. При повторном проверяете, сколько прошло времени с момента последнего запроса у текущей сессии. Если ок, то разрешаем запрос, иначе - говорим об ошибке, мол 1 раз в 5 минут

Comment: @ЕвгенийСафронов лучше проверьте, есть ли такие данные в бд, если мы говорим о заявках в привычном понимании. Грубо говоря, если там указывается номер телефона, то заявки с этим же номером, не сохраняются

Comment: бд не использую, все идет напрямую в телеграм

Comment: @ЕвгенийСафронов тогда только вышеперечисленными способами

Answer (score 0):

На фронте можно отключить кнопку пока выполняется запрос, к примеру:

```
jQuery('#formsc').click('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = jQuery('#name').val();
  var phone = jQuery('#phone').val();

  if (phone != '') {
    this.disabled = true;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "send/send.php",
      data: jQuery('form#formsc').serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        this.disabled = false;
        window.location.href = "sucs.html";
        console.log('Ok, send!');
      },
      error: function () {
        this.disabled = false;
        console.log('Error. Not send.');
      }
    },);
  }
});
```

После чего либо очистить форму либо перезагрузить страницу.

Comment: Да, спасибо помогло!